# I am trying to run the following simple code from 'Automate the boring stuff with Python' Chapter 11

Tags: python, ssl

When I try and run the following code from 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' - Chapter 11, I get an error stating the SSL module is not avaliable. So I installed the SSL module and I get a different error saying the DLL load failed and the specified module could not be found. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

I installed 'Dependency Walker' to try and find which DLL file is missing or in the wrong place. But, as far as I can see, this is only good for determining the dependencies for applications and cannot determine dependencies for python code.

```
import requests, _ssl

res=requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt')

print(res.text[:250])
```

First error:

> "Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
>   urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

Second error when _ssl is also imported:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Looks like the module you installed is a different bitness from the Python interpreter that is trying to load it. If the DLL is there but the wrong bitness Windows will often say it can't find it.

Comment: How do I check for the bitness of the module and is there a module of the correct bitness that would do the same job?

Comment: `sys.version` at the Python prompt will tell you about your installation, for example `MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)`.  Wheels that you install generally have AMD64 or similar in the name somewhere if bitness matters and they are 64 bit. Be very sure to run `pip` from the `Scripts` folder of the Python installation where you want the module installed. Else you may get `pip` for a different Python version that happens to come earlier on your path. If `pip` can't find an installation of the appropriate bitness it will issue an error message, something about `no installation for your platform.`